# Add Related list to customized Edit Form in Sharepoomt 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

So I am trying to update a site from 2010 to 2013. The site has a list called vendors and a library called Invoices. Invoices have a lookup column on vendors.  The Invoice edit page was customized in SPD 2010 in two ways:

1. The ListFormWebPart was hidden and a custom DataFormWebPart was added to let the user edit the metadata of the invoice.
2. A related List View was added so that users could see a list of invoices for the vendor being edited.

After upgrading the site to SharePoint 2013, the fields on the DataFormWebPart  do not get rendered. If I remove the hidden ListFormWebPart, then The DataFormWebPart display its fields ok, but the related list shows nothing (the related list must get filtered using the ListFormWebPart).

I tried to recreate the scenario in a new SPWeb from scratch in 2013 and got the same results (I could not have a customized DataFormWebPart  AND  a related list view on an edit form.)

Is there any way to get this to work in 2013 as it did in 2010?

I’m thinking I could replace my related list with some JavaScript to pull the Invoice info and display it, but I am hoping there is an easier workaround.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, I undid the listformwebpart  and removed the dfwp. The javascript solution should work too but would take time to develop. Customizations I had in the dfwp wer changed to car modifications in the listformwebpart.